# What type of fittings go in and out of a shower water filter? (and/or, what type of fitting does a shower head use?)

Tags: plumbing, pipe-fitting

For a shower water filter like this: https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/spec/GXSM01HWW

What are the connectors? The specs say "standard 1/2" shower head and pipe connections".

Is this 1/2 OD or ID?

Is it IP/NPT?

Is it tapered? Compression?

If it's NOT compression, does that mean there are no washers involved? If it's not compression and does have a washer, is this surprising? Is it a hack that the manufacturer does so that the consumer does not need to deal with teflon tape?

[image: GE shower water filter]
[image: GE shower water filter attached to supply and shower head]

Answer (score 2):

The specifications you pointed to state: Plumbing Connections   standard 1/2" shower head and pipe connections. That is a standard trade size 1/2" pipe in the USA. Standard parts would fit without any problem. No washers are needed as the pipe has a slight taper to it. That taper is generated when the threads are cut, deeper on the end of the pipe and getting shallower as you get away from the end. The pipe is not tapered. It is 0.5" Id, and 0.84" Od with 14 threads per inch.

From your picture you do not need anything, simply remove the head, screw on the filter, then attach the shower head and you are ready to go. If the directions do not tell you to use joint compound or teflon tape do not use it.

Comment: Thanks - the female portion does have a washer - is this unexpected for a tapered fitting? Is it a "hack" so that consumers don't need teflon tape?

Comment: In my experience whenever the threaded fitting is plastic, they usually use a rubber washer on the female side. The tapered threading was developed for metal pipe and I suspect typical plastic isn't strong enough to be tightened without cracking. A rubber washer/gasket on the female side only needs to be tightened enough to slightly compress that washer to conform to the male pipe end and female seat.

Comment: gotcha - so, just to be clear, if one were to look for compatible things to attatch to either end, would those be "1/2 inch MIP/FIP"? Anything more specific? (with caveats that this is a plastic hand-tightened consumer product and might not behave like an arbitrary component)